# How do I mock certain objects of a class being tested?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I've the below class that I want to test:

```
@Component
public class ToBeTested {
 @Autowired
 private HelperA helperA;

 @Autowired
 private HelperB helperB;

 ... //10 other such helpers
}
```

I want to mock ONLY HelperA class. How do I do this in jUnit? I do not want to mock the other helper classes. Nor do I want to write @Spy & @Resource for all of the helpers and use @InjectMocks in the test case.

Is there a way for me to inject only the mock of HelperA into the ToBeTested class in the test case?

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you want to use a mocked `HelperA` but an `@Autowired` `HelperB`?

I wrote an article on this that can help: http://www.sleepeasysoftware.com/how-to-mock-out-a-deeply-nested-class-in-spring-without-going-insane/

To summarize, put this at the top of your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ASubclassOfYourRealConfig.class)
```

Then you create `ASubclassOfYourRealConfig` to look like this:

```
public class ASubclassOfYourRealConfig extends YourRealConfig {


   @Bean
   public HelperA getHelperA() {
       return mock(HelperA.class);
   }

}
```

In your test class, you can `@Autowire` `HelperA` like normal, but it will actually be mocked by Mockito in that test.

Answer (score 0):

If you ONLY want helperB, then you'll need `@InjectMocks`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest() {

@InjectMocks
public ToBeTested toBeTested;

@Mock 
private HelperB helperB;

...your tests go here

}
```

Of course, this will leave your helperA `null`. If you want to have both, you will simply need a Spring configuration for your tests, set helperB as a mock bean (via factory methods) and run the whole thing with the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` )

Comment: If I use @InjectMocks, don't I have to instantiate the class as below?
`@InjectMocks
public ToBeTested toBeTested = new ToBeTested();`

Comment: InjectMocks will try to instantiate the class for you, see http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html - That way, it can even try to use constructor injection.